# macOS Sierra log issue cant find on Console any log info

Tags: bash, macos, shell, logging, macos-sierra

I have created a script which should update logs message on console or on system.log this is working fine on old osx 10.11i can search on console app on 10.11. But cant find any log in macOS 10.12.3. i just want log on console. i know we cant save logs on system.log on Sierra or something like that any more but then what what should i do to work on Sierra teh same script. or if  i do to console and search (com.skull.testScript) it should search. guys kindly help :|

```
#!/bin/bash

# Keep log of what we're upto.
logme() {
    if [ -n "$DEBUG" ]; then
        echo "$*"
    fi
    logger -t com.skull.testScript "$*"
}

# Realitychecks
echo "Hello world"
logme "NOTE: printed successfully"

mkdir /Users/skull/Desktop/test_101
logme "NOTE: DIR created"
```

Comment: You can use the `log` command (for instance, `log stream` which is similar to `tail -f /var/log/system.log`).

Answer (score 1):

This works fine on macOS Sierra, though the tag specified with `-t` is ignored. Running your function, I get this output:

[image: screenshot]